# How yolo v1 handle negative predicted values?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, pytorch, yolo

Let suppose if model generate negative w1 and h1, how can yolo handle this? It will produce a nan value and any other value added to it becomes nan.
So is there any idea, how yolo handle it?

[image: Yolo loss]

Comment: Simple, the model does not produce negative width/height, it was designed that wway.

Comment: do you mean the architecture of it?

Comment: The activation functions at the output neurons that produce bounding box coordinates

Comment: actually i tried to implement it and my model is giving negative predictions for w and h

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, you need to actually describe the problem you have, including code and results.

Comment: no, actually x and y positive, actually my task is to indentify single class with single bounding box, so may be that is because of this?

Comment: @TalhaAnwar It's been more than a year since this question was asked, but i was wondering have you solved the problem, since I find myself facing the same? Btw, adding to the previous comment, the original net uses Leaky Relu, which can output negative values.

Comment: i did not remember exactly, but one way is to convert negative number to zero, like as relu do.